# ASP: integrating HTTPS

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to integrate https on my web application. This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) describes what should I do in IIS. Is there any other thing i should do in my web application regarding `web.config`? seriously I have no idea at all on how to do this. Any support would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope all you need to do is get a certificate and install it in IIS, bind your host to port 443 and you should be good to go. Your app should run as-is on there.

Good resource [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. With the link I provided a self signed certificate is created. Is it ok to create self signed certificates? If no, are there any free certificates ?

Comment: Self-signed certificates won't be recognized by any browsers without adding the cert to the store on each client machine. www.startssl.com has free certificates. The site isn't very easy to use, but i have generated multiple free certs from there that work great.

Comment: My GOD 6 hours to authenticate the accout !! , Anyways thanks for the help really appreciate it !!